# Changing colour of specific words in a text box

Tags: vb.net

I am writing code for a forest simulation in VB. I want to change the colour of numbers that I implement into my textboxes

here is one line:

```
Console.WriteLine("Number of fir trees cut " & fircut)
```

What do I do to only change the colour of fircut (one of my variables) and not the whole line whilst keeping it in one sentence?

I've already tried subs with code and placing them in the brackets but have no clue what to do

Comment: Is that text going into a `System.Windows.Forms.TextBox`?

Comment: TextBox does not support coloring words, you have to use RichTextBox.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13583494/change-the-color-of-a-line-or-a-word-in-a-richtextbox

Answer (score 0):

Please see this answer to achieve what you are intending to achieve: [Color in Console Application](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19625120/18920732).

An improvement on the above would be to pass a string into a sub that parses over the string looking for numbers which can then split the string and write to your console accordingly.

Comment: A console app is not the same as a TextBox.

Comment: OP is using a `Console.WriteLine()` command in his OP. While OP said textbox they have not shown any code indicating they are actually using any sort of text box. As such, the above link provides a solution printing to the console as seen in the OP. It is likely safe to assume that OP is unfamiliar with what exactly they are working with considering the nature of the question itself.

Comment: Well, one of us is clearly clueless, and it isn't you :)

Comment: Oh, but I am. :)